# Bumping package-lock.json and packge.lock at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Prior to publishing to NPM I need to bump the minor version.  What I usually do is: 
- Change `package.json`
- Run `npm i` which syncs `package-lock.json` with the change.  Now both can be published.

Is there a way to do this with a single NPM command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [npm version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version.html).

For example, the following command

```
npm version 1.0.2
```

will bump both `package.json` and `package-lock.json` to `1.0.2`

Comment: Note that if You use `git` in your package, than this command also **adds a commit** with the version number (eg. "1.0.2") as the message and **tags** it with the new version automatically.

Comment: I started using @jsdevtools/version-bump-prompt ( `npm install -g @jsdevtools/version-bump-prompt` ) ... This way I can bump and update both `package-lock.json` and `package.json` from scripts and so I have a single publish script like this: `bump patch && npm publish`.

Comment: I did a writeup on it here: https://developer.fireflysemantics.com/tasks/tasks--npm--automatically-bumping-the-npm-package-semver-patch-version

Answer (score 1):

The following command

```
npm i -S <module>@<version>
```

installs the specific version of the given module.

`-S` or `--save` tells npm to save the reference of the module + version into both `package.json` and `package-lock.json`

Comment: That would install the `module@version` ... in this case I have a module that I want to publish to NPM and before publishing I need to bump the minor version and update `package-lock.json`.  I updated the question.  Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Posted a new answer

Comment: Bingo!  Exactly what I was looking for - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the granularity of control you want to have. For example, if you just want to check for an *update on an individual module* you can run: `npm update <pkg>`. As this command will *update your `package.json` file to save the newest version of this `<pkg>` as the now required version to build your project*. Alternatively, you could run `npm update` to *update all your project's top-level packages*. Ok so those are the more general use cases but if you **want a specific version of a package and you know the version** of which you desire you can do the following: `npm i --save <pkg>@<version>` as this command will grab the package specified by your version number as well as update the `package.json` file to *include this version of package as now being required to build your project*. This will eliminate the need to first update the `package.json` file and then installing the newer version of said package, rather this will be condensed down to one step. Lastly, just for thoroughness the `package-lock.json` file is *dynamically generated when you make important changes to your project*, such as requiring new dependencies or updating existing dependencies. This file kind of serves as source of truth so others can build your project and have the same setup as you, for more information on this file take a look at the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks)

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Sorry I should have made the question clearer.  In this case I'm trying to update the version of `package.json` and `package-lock.json` prior to publishing.  I updated the question.  Hopefully it's clearer now.